# Sitecore 8 - Clear Custom Profile Field for All Users

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

What's the best way to set a custom profile field in Sitecore 8 user profiles to blank for all user profiles?

Answer (score 0):

How many users do you have?
I would say that a small Powershell for Sitecore script will be the easiest. Now if you have more than 20000 users I would directlly change it into the users database (core by default)

Answer (score 0):

I have ~1.25 million users. I didn't want to just fire and forget but wanted to ensure progress was being made and if for some reason it errored out I didn't want to have to start over from square one. What I ended up doing was writing a Powershell script that iterates through users based on the first character of their user id...update a*....then b*...and so on. Not insanely fast, but effective.

Comment: Turns out it's hit or miss and I'm struggling to find why some records update and others don't. I run the following script in PowerShell. Some age values clear, some don't.

$i=0;
$users = Get-User -Filter "extranet\a*"
foreach($user in $users){
    write-host "Updating $($user.Name)`n"
    $user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Age","")
    $i++
}

write-host "`n`n";
write-host "Script Completed.`n`n";
write-host "$($i) records processed";
write-host "`n`n";